# This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. Spring Boot / Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, https

I have a problem with my app. The backend is done with Spring boot and the front end with Angular. The two are on different servers. The font end is on a secure server and the backend is on an insecure server and it gives me the following error.

polyfills.9589fb3cb9f5b3ee.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://vcrm.malisoft.ml/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://194.135.90.77:8080/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: mate did you solve that problem how did you do it? please I am really stuck same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change all  API calls to use HTTPs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).